# For a $C^{\infty}$ function, is it true that $|f'(x)| \leq 1$ implies that $|f(x)| \leq x$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, lipschitz-functions, functional-inequalities

Let $f(x)$ be a nice/$C^{\infty}$ function of some real-variable $x$ which satisfies the inequality
$$
|f'(x)| \leq 1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{for\ all\ }x>0
$$
If this is true, does this imply that
$$
|f(x)| \leq |x| \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{for\ all\ }x>0?
$$
Or something similar? This seems to follow by ``integrating both sides''. I've come up with some functions where this seems to be the case (for example $f'(x) = \tanh(x)$ satisfies $|f'(x)| \leq 1$, and $f(x) = \log(\cosh(x))$ satisfies $|f(x)| < |x|$).

If this is true, how can you prove it?

If this is not true, what is an example of a counter-example?

Comment: What about $f(x) = 123$?

Comment: If $f(0)=0$ then yes, from MVT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate a bit: the condition
$$
|f'(x)| \leq 1\quad\text{ for all } x>0
$$
does not imply any bound on $f$ because $f$ can be shifted by a constant and the derivative does not change. For example, we could shift $f$ up by $100$, down by $1000$, and so on, and the derivative would not change.

A concrete counterexample is given in the comments: if $f(x) = 1000$, then $|f'(x)| = 0$ so it is bounded by $1$, but $|f(x)|$ is not bounded by $|x|$.

So, if you want the bound on $|f(x)|$, you need to additionally specify something like $f(0) = 0$. In general, the best bound you can have is
$$
|f(x)| \le |x| + |f(0)|,
$$
which follows by Traingle inequality from Martin's answer.

**P.S.:** A particular consequence of the bound on the derivative $|f'(x)| \le 1$ that your function $f$ is [Lipschitz continuous](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LipschitzFunction.html) with constant $1$.

Comment: Assuming we have the bound $|f(x) - f(0)| \leq |x|$. The triangle inequality seems to tell me that $|f(x) - f(0)| \leq |f(x)| + |f(0)|$. But I don't see how your inequality $|f(x)| \leq |x| + |f(0)|$ follows from this. What am I missing?

Comment: @Greg.Paul There is a second useful form of triangle inequality: $|a - b| \ge |a| - |b|$. To see why this is the same as the usual triangle inequality, you can write $a = b + a'$, and the formula becomes $|a'| \ge |b + a'| - |b|$, which rearranges to $|b + a'| \le |a'| + |b|$. (Follow the steps backwards to go from the regular triangle inequality to this second form)

Comment: Anyway, using that form of triangle inequality, we have
$|f(x) - f(0)| \ge |f(x)| - |f(0)|$. Therefore, $|f(x) \le |f(0)| + |f(x) - f(0)| \le |f(0)| + |x|$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks I blanked on that one!

Answer (score 4):

$|f'(x)| \leq 1 $ for $x > 0$ implies that $|f(x) - f(0)| \le |x|$ for $x \ge 0$, that is an immediate consequence of the [mean-value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

You don't need $C^\infty$ for this conclusion, it suffices that $f$ is  continuous for $x \ge 0$ and differentiable for $x > 0$.

If in addition $f(0) = 0$ then indeed $|f(x)| \le |x|$.

Comment: The MVT says that $f$ needs to be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and then there always exists a $a<c<b$ where $f'(c) = [ f(b) - f(a) ] / (b-a)$. Here is seems like you're picking $a=0$ and $b=x$, and then $c=x$. This doesn't seem kosher to me because $b=c$ here...what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Ahh, never mind. I got it now. Pick $a=0$ and $b=x > 0$. By the MVT there exists a $0 < c < x$ where $f'(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}$. The bound $|f'(c)| \leq 1$ then implies that $| \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} | \leq 1$ from which the statement follows. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take $$f(x)=\cos(x)$$

then

$f$ is $C^{\infty}$ and
$$|f'(x)|\le 1$$

but

$$f(0.00001)>0.00001$$